# Import Bootpag pagination plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-bootpag

Has anyone had luck with importing Bootpag as an ES6 module? This is the only pagination plugin that I found to have all the functionalities that I need but I can't seem to import it. The npm package is here :https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootpag

I tried

```
import bootpag from 'bootpag'
import * as bootpag from 'bootpag'
```

but all i get is errors:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: "__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_jquery___default(...)(...).bootpag is not a function"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
import 'bootpag/lib/jquery.bootpag.min';
```